# Xampp - MS SQL - PHP 5.5

Tags: php, xampp, sqlsrv

I'm trying to get the PDO SQL driver to work with my Xampp and PHP 5.5 installation. I have followed the directions found below as Microsoft has yet to make a PHP 5.5 SQL driver:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see by the images I have downloaded the file, placed it into my `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder and added it to `php.ini` and restarted apache.

But still when running `phpinfo();` it shows it as not loaded. What did I do wrong?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Error log for PHP shows this:

```
[25-Sep-2014 14:22:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[25-Sep-2014 14:22:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the PHP ERROR LOG? Or maybe even in the Windoes Event Viewer?

Comment: No errors in either log.

Comment: I assume you have not turned error logging off!?

Comment: Sorry, was looking in the wrong log file. I was looking in error_log from apache as that's what PHP for Linux does. PHP for Windows in Xammp has it's own log file. I'll add information now for the logs.

Comment: Did you check permissions of those two files from right click -> properties?

Comment: Yeah, that's not the problem: http://i.imgur.com/BxhsPvt.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems by using Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com) I found out that the modules couldn't find `php5ts.dll` file, even though it was directory up.

So I edited the Windows 2008 R2 Environment Variables and added `C:\xampp\php` to the Path variable and it worked like a charm.

I used the instructions here on how to edit the variables in Windows:

http://thommck.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/how-to-add-a-path-to-the-system-variables-in-windows-2008-r2/

Comment: I have just spent 3 hours finding for a solution. I tried everything. Adding the correct path variable and restarting apache worked for me. You sir, are a hero.

Comment: weird issue... i've had this situation in a 2012 server, and a 2012 datacenter edition R2, none of them were able to recognize the path to php. dunno why, but this only happens (in my experience) when running PHP from XAMPP. thanks a lot for the tip.